# How to update k8s pod to newer version of image after minikube image load

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I'm trying to make a development environment using minikube.
I'm using `minikube image load` to upload local images to the cluster.
here is an example deployment:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: sso
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mm
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mm
        name: sso
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: sso
          image: sso-service
          imagePullPolicy: Never
          resources:
            limits:
              memory: "128Mi"
              cpu: "500m"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3000
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: pull-secret
```

The first time I run `minikube image load "sso-service"` the deployment restarts, but after that, loading a new image doesn't cause a rollout with the new image.
I also tried running `kubectl rollout restart`, did not help.
Is there any way to force the deployment to perform a rollout with the new image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to solve this myself.
I made a script that would first generate a random number and use it as the image's tag, it would then use `kubectl set image` to update the image.

```
$tag = $(Get-Random)
echo "building image"
docker build --build-arg NPM_TOKEN=$(cat .token) -t "sso-service:$tag" .
echo "loading image"
minikube image load "sso-service:$tag" --daemon=true
kubectl set image deployment/sso sso="sso-service:$tag"
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the `imagePullPolicy` from `Never` to `Always` in your deployment manifest.

In short.

`Never` - The container image is never pulled from the registry.

`Always` - The image is pulled every time the container is (re)started.

To get more info run the following command:

```
kubectl explain pod.spec.containers.imagePullPolicy
```

Comment: This forces a pull from the registry, I don't want it to pull from the registry because the registry's image doesn't have the local changes. I've found a solution (which you can see above) but thank you for the help